# Cutting a rectangular hollow into lumber -- what is the correct term?

Tags: terminology

Any tips on how to do what I'm asking are welcome, but first of all I would like to ask for the correct terminology (because not knowing it prevents me from even Googling myself).

Maybe the title is not totally clear (because I don't know the right term), so let me explain in detail:

- suppose you have a thicker plank or other dimension lumber, something like this [image: log]
- now let's say, you want to make the middle part more deep in a rectangular area, but not cut completely through the lumber, like this:

```
              +---------------------+
              |                     <------ untouched part
              | +-----------------+ |
              | |                 | |
              | |               <---------- deeper, flat, but not   
              | |                 | |       cut through surface
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | |                 | |
              | +-----------------+ |
              |                     |
              +---------------------+
```

One example use case, just to give an idea, would be building a table top from which the tools (like screw drivers, pencils, etc.) cannot roll down.
(The actual use case I'm planning to do, is building a base for a power-strip, inspired by [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/138302/48568).)

**Questions**

- What is this process called? (I thought I remembered something like "embeveling", but that is not the correct word, because it means "chopping off the edge at a degree.) -- This is actually the most important.
- What tools can be used to do this?
- What is the procedure for doing this?

Comment: For future reference this is too many queries in one. The follow-on query on the tools to create a recess is fine, the one on how is a Question in its own right.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: My new fav youtuber  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPGa5QBQHmQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the words that fit your objective are mortise and recess. Typically a mortise is an opening cut part way into wood to receive a tenon to create a strong joint. A mortise is described also as a recess. You can also use inlay to find other useful references.

For a large area project as you describe, a set of chisels and gouges would be useful if you intend to perform this action using hand tools.

[image: wood chisels for carving]

A method using power tools requires either a router table or a router jig. One could attempt the process without either, but the depth of the recess would be inconsistent and may not result in an acceptable appearance.

A more comprehensive answer can be found on [this SE](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/how-to-make-a-recess-in-a-board).